# Pandas best way to one-hot for big data? from long format to wide format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, market-basket-analysis

I tried to convert dataframe for the market basket analysis

```
Sales Order Number, Product Category, Product, SKU Quantity
A123, Book, book of python, 1
A123, Book, book of java, 2
A123, Book, how to sleep well, 1
A300, Book, English speaking, 1
...............................
```

when I wanna to convert the dataframe as the following formate by the code below, it casue error due to more than 10208 different "product".

```
Sales Order Number, book of python, book of java,how to sleep well,English speaking ..... 
            A123,        1,    2,     1,    0,    0,    0,...0
            A300,        0,    0,     0,    1,    0,    0,...0
```

(more than 10K columns --> memory issue)

```
basket = (df[df['Product Category'] == "Book"].groupby(['Sales Order Number', 'Product'])['SKU Quantity'].sum().unstack().reset_index().fillna(0).set_index('Sales Order Number'))
```

May I know any good idea to solve the issue so that the program can convert the big data?

Thanks

Comment: is it possible to get the top N product (based on the number of quantity )first then do the cross tabulation? I assume that only 30% of 10Kproducts are the common product that people usually buy. it would be good if we can focus on the main products.

Comment: At a certain point memory is going to be a problem with this approach. You can look at Apache Spark as a distributed way to do this kind of work. To test your model you may want to filter out products that haven't been bought often as they may not perform very well in your model anyway